# How to add custom fields to post_type 'page'?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

How can I add custom meta box with custom fields to the post_type 'page' without plugins ?

I know how I can add this to custom post types, but I have problems to make it with native post types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow below steps:

```
menu >> pages >> add new >> screen options >> custom fields
```

Comment: hm...

but with this technique I'll be able to just make a simple list of key-> value?! I can not make big enough custom meta boxes ..

Comment: you can create custom meta box like explained here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box. Just use  $screens = array( 'page' );